# Foo.objects.get(id=None) returns Foo instance, sometimes

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, innodb

I have this code:

```
try:
    parent_comment = models.Comment.all_objects.get(id=parent_comment_id)
except models.Comment.DoesNotExist:
    parent_comment = None

if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment_id is None:
    raise Exception("WTF django/mysql")
```

... and sometimes, the exception somehow gets raised. How could this ever happen?

Once in a while, several times a day, it returns seemingly random Comment instances. Usually it behaves as expected and returns None.

This is the id field of the Comment table: `id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` so it's not that it's nullable. It's an InnoDB table.

As for Comment.all_objects, this is its definition: `all_objects = Manager()` and it's the first line in that class.

We're on Django 1.2.7.

**Update**
Added logging to the exception to get the SQL that's generated when the exception is raised. Here it is:

```
SELECT `canvas_comment`.`id`, `canvas_comment`.`visibility`, `canvas_comment`.`parent_content_id`, `canvas_comment`.`parent_comment_id`, `canvas_comment`.`timestamp`, `canvas_comment`.`reply_content_id`, `canvas_comment`.`reply_text`, `canvas_comment`.`replied_comment_id`, `canvas_comment`.`category_id`, `canvas_comment`.`author_id`, `canvas_comment`.`title`, `canvas_comment`.`ip`, `canvas_comment`.`anonymous`, `canvas_comment`.`score`, `canvas_comment`.`judged`, `canvas_comment`.`ot_hidden` FROM `canvas_comment` WHERE `canvas_comment`.`id` IS NULL
```

Comment: Where did you define the parent_comment_id on the 5th line? I can't find it in your code.

Comment: @sza it's irrelevant - I'm asking about how the exception is able to be raised, which happens when parent_comment_id is None.

Comment: Ok. But if you haven't defined it or assigned it with a value before, it is definitely None. Can you paste the code relating the parent_comment_id assignment? Thanks!

Comment: @sza python doesn't work that way - if it hasn't been defined before, it would raise a NameError exception.

Comment: @sza can't for other reasons.

Comment: can we get your model's definition?

Comment: Perhaps you could boil it down to the simplest test-case: `assertRaises(models.Comment.DoesNotExist, models.Comment.all_objects.get, id=None)` to see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: @supervacuo I don't see how that will help. That assert will fail whenever this exception gets raised, because that's equivalent to what my code is doing.

Comment: @aehlke I just wanted to make sure that was *actually* what it was doing. Which (according to your SQL) it definitely is. Hmm.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by deeply strange (in this coder's humble opinion) MySQL behaviour, controlled [by the `SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL` variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_auto_is_null) (which is `1` by default in MySQL < 5.5.3):

> If this variable is set to 1, then after a statement that successfully inserts an automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT value, you can find that value by issuing a statement of the following form:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE auto_col IS NULL
> ```
>
> If the statement returns a row, the value returned is the same as if you invoked the LAST_INSERT_ID() function

There is [a Django bug (closed: wontfix) describing similar confusion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10339) caused by this "feature", in which a core developer states

> If you don't want that behaviour, you should configure your database to do the right thing for your preferences

The solution, then, is to disable the `SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL` option of your MySQL database [using the `SET` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html). You can do this in `settings.py` with something like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # ... your DB options
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0;'
        },
    }
}
```

Longer-term, you can try and drum-beat on [the django-developers list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers) to get them to reconsider [their earlier position](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-developers/1BgLit316XA%5B1-25%5D):

> Fortunately, my thinking here isn't burning any bridges. If somebody
>   wanted to test that out, or use it by default, they can use the database
>   initialisation options via DATABASE_OPTIONS in settings ... Both
>   "read_default_file" and "init_command" are useful there.
>
> I'm not saying this should be "no, forever", but right now I'm not
>   convinced it's worth doing this. Balanced against that is how to let
>   people know that it might happen... *shrug*.. I might add something to
>   databases.txt, for a start. I hate this sort of balancing act. :-(

Answer (score 1):

To rule out simple stuff:

1. Could you post your Comment model
2. Could you run the following query against your DB

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM <your_comment_table> WHERE id <= 0 OR id ='' OR id IS NULL`

Your code logically should work barring something wonky in your model code, which leads me to believe that it must be data related.

## EDIT

another idea, see what django's ORM is querying (this should tell us whats up):

```
parent_comment = models.Comment.all_objects.get(id=parent_comment_id)
raise Exception(parent_comment.query) # should display out the query thats being generated
```

Comment: Your query returns 0 rows. Added the generated SQL to the question.